# SAS - Column Pointer Error when Importing COBOL Structured Data

Tags: io, sas

I have a structure MF file that I'm now trying to import into SAS. The fixed portion of the record is working, but when I hit the Days line the column pointer is at 30. The variable is at 15. How did the column pointer jump to 30 vs my expected value and how can I update the below.

```
data test;
INFILE file1 recfm=N;
INPUT seqno s370fPD9.
   type $ebcdic2.
   record_type $ebcdic1.
   occurs s370fPD2.
 @;

ARRAY Day{60} Day1-Day60;
ARRAY AMT{60} AMT1-AMT60;
ARRAY CRED{60} CRED1-CRED60; 
ARRAY PAY{60} PAY1-PAY60; 

DO I = 1 TO OCCURS;
input Days{I} s370fPD2.  
     AMT{I} s370fPD6. +2
     CRED{I} s370fPD6. +2
     PAY{I} s370fPD8. @;
end;
run;
```

I get the following in the log. While there isn't a note for Amt1, it is not populated correctly:

```
NOTE: INVALID DATA for Days1 at byte position 30-31.
NOTE: INVALID DATA for CRED1 at byte position 52-57.
NOTE: INVALID DATA for PAY1 at byte position 70-71.
```

For the first record, days1 should be at 15. Cred1 at 25 Pay1 at 33.

Comment: I question the use of RECFM=N when you make reference "For the first record".  Do you have record layout documentation?

Comment: I do, but the length of a record is dependent on the var OCCUR. One record could be  40. Then next could be 1730 (the max length for 66 occurs). I just tried recfm=F and the issue with the column pointer is resolved, I think. Days1 is now at 15, but it's the wrong format.

Comment: If the RECFM is variable then use RECFM=V.  Do you know how to use the LIST statement to get a record dump?

Comment: I did not about LIST, and that turned out to be extremely useful. Thank you. I got to a working solution, but never found out why the column pointer was jumping so much. I did need to use refcm=V and the type and Days were s370fIB2 instead of chars.